# Refactor my javascript code and I need a way how to prevent the text repeated when the mouse on?

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I’m a beginner in JS could somebody help me please
I have created an HTML page with 3 country’s flags. When the user moves the mouse over one of the flags, display the name of the country in the text box. When they move the mouse away from the flag, clear the text box.

The problem is when I move the mouse on the flag many times the text repeated
Also how to refactor my code it is so repeated I know I must use foreach but how?   here is my code

```js
const photo = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.flag-img'));
const oman = document.querySelector('.oman');
const algeria = document.querySelector('.algeria');
const uae = document.querySelector('.uae');
const div1 = document.createElement("div1");
const div2 = document.createElement("div2");
const div3 = document.createElement("div3");

function countryName() {
  const text1 = document.createTextNode("Oman");
  div1.appendChild(text1);
  div1.className = "box";
  oman.appendChild(div1);
}

function countryAlg() {
  const text2 = document.createTextNode("Algeria");
  div2.appendChild(text2);
  div2.className = "box";
  algeria.appendChild(div2);
}

function countryUae() {
  const text3 = document.createTextNode("UAE");
  div3.appendChild(text3);
  div3.className = "box";
  uae.appendChild(div3);
}

function fadeOut() {
  div1.parentNode.removeChild(div1);
}

function fadeOut2() {
  div2.parentNode.removeChild(div2);
}

function fadeOut3() {
  div3.parentNode.removeChild(div3);
}

oman.addEventListener('mouseenter', countryName);
algeria.addEventListener('mouseenter', countryAlg);
uae.addEventListener('mouseenter', countryUae);
oman.addEventListener('mouseleave', fadeOut);
algeria.addEventListener('mouseleave', fadeOut2);
uae.addEventListener('mouseleave', fadeOut3);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}

#flag {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flag-img img {
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  /*position: absolute;
              left: 50px;
              top: 50px;*/
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Countries Flags</h1>
</header>
<div id="flag">
  <div class="flag-img oman">
    <img src="https://motionarray.imgix.net/preview-339277phSMy7aPd_0007.jpg?w=750&q=60&fit=max&auto=format">
  </div>
  <div class="flag-img algeria">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/flag-of-algeria_1401-52.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="flag-img uae">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/255px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solution without JS: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/f51h2zsa/ (check end of CSS) Using mouse events instead of hover: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/t8rx9d5v/

Comment: For this problem you might not need JS, you can use `title` attribute in the HTML. `<img src="link.com/to/your/image.png" title="Oman" />` for the hover text.

Comment: when answering, you should teach the OP why the code is 'broken' - not just simply rewrite it for them, especially in a different language !!!

Comment: You need to pick an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to refractor this in your way :

Select all your elements

```
 var flags = document.getElementsByClassName("flag-img");
```

Init elements with function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
(function () {
console.log(flags[i]);
    var elem = flags[i];
    flags[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    showCountry(elem)
  }, false);
  flags[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    fadeOut(elem)
  }, false);    
  }());
}
```

Single function fadeout

```
 function fadeOut(a) {
    a.removeChild(a.lastChild);
}
```

Single function show.

```
 function showCountry(a) {  
   const text = document.createTextNode(a.className.split(" ")[1]);
         var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.appendChild(text);
   div.className = "box";
        a.appendChild(div);     
}
```

```js
   console.clear();

    var flags = document.getElementsByClassName("flag-img");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
    (function () {
     var elem = flags[i];
     flags[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
       showCountry(elem)
      }, false);
      flags[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
       fadeOut(elem)
      }, false);    
      }());
    }
    
     function fadeOut(a) {
        a.removeChild(a.lastChild);
    }
    
    
     function showCountry(a) {  
       const text = document.createTextNode(a.className.split(" ")[1]);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
       div.appendChild(text);
       div.className = "box";
       a.appendChild(div);     
    }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}

#flag {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flag-img img {
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  /*position: absolute;
              left: 50px;
              top: 50px;*/
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Countries Flags</h1>
</header>
<div id="flag">
  <div class="flag-img oman">
    <img src="https://motionarray.imgix.net/preview-339277phSMy7aPd_0007.jpg?w=750&q=60&fit=max&auto=format">
  </div>
  <div class="flag-img algeria">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/flag-of-algeria_1401-52.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="flag-img uae">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/255px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your code it worked perfectly but its little complicated for me since I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

instead of for loop I used forEach because i hate for loops 
and the code worked

```
var flags =  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("flag-img"));

   flags.forEach(function(value) {

      value.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    showCountry(value)
  }, false);
       value.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    fadeOut(value)
  }, false);    
    });

 function fadeOut(a) {
    a.removeChild(a.lastChild);
}


 function showCountry(a) {  
   const text = document.createTextNode(a.className.split(" ")[1]);
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.appendChild(text);
   div.className = "box";
        a.appendChild(div);     
}
```

Comment: `for … of` is more idiomatic than `forEach` and works much better in may situations. Try to avoid `forEach`.

Comment: @Bergi Disagree - it only works better if you don't understand `this` in Javascript. Aside from that it has relevant downsides with regard to how Babel transpiles `for...of` (which requires two polyfills in IE11) https://daverupert.com/2017/10/for-of-loops-are-bad/

Comment: @connexo I don't see what `forEach` has to do with `this`? I mean that it works better with regard to `return`, `break`, `continue`, `yield` and `await`… it should simply be the default loop structure. Also usually you should not need to care about Internet Explorer - don't let it impact your code style until it becomes a significant problem.

Comment: @Bergi As soon as Babel with a preset including IE 11 is part of your build stack - which in 95% of projects is - you end up with the code described in the article I linked.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're trying to learn Javascript, but this is far easier (and better performance-wise) to achieve using CSS only:

```css
#flag {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

#flag img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.flag-img::after {
  display: block;
  content: attr(data-country);
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

.flag-img:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="flag">
  <div class="flag-img" data-country="Oman">
    <img src="https://motionarray.imgix.net/preview-339277phSMy7aPd_0007.jpg?w=750&q=60&fit=max&auto=format">
  </div>
  <div class="flag-img" data-country="Algeria">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/flag-of-algeria_1401-52.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="flag-img" data-country="United Arab Emirate">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg/255px-Flag_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates.svg.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when answering, you should teach the OP why the code is 'broken' - not just simply rewrite it for them, especially in a different language !!!

Comment: @RozzA Disagreed. It's perfectly valid to suggest an alternative solution and if that is as short and speaking as the above, I'd always wait for OP to ask, should anthing be not clear to them.

Comment: Thank you my main concern to learn javascript but I learned new way in css i didn't know before